# Change orientation of CSS grid

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I want to make all columns into rows for small devices. Is it possible to do so with a CSS grid? I am using GatsbyJS and Tailwind CSS.

Here's the code:

```
const contentList = [
  {
    title: 'Text 1',
    year: 2021,
    body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin rhoncus finibus quam, condimentum tincidunt erat pharetra ac. Nunc ante sapien, congue vitae felis nec, lobortis viverra augue. Integer vitae nibh vel nunc finibus placerat. Aliquam tincidunt magna eros, nec maximus neque accumsan eget. Etiam vitae convallis massa. Donec diam nulla, volutpat a rutrum nec, pulvinar sit amet neque. Donec eleifend ut magna varius condimentum. Morbi eu erat et dolor porta porttitor eget vitae mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus ornare, risus id ornare sagittis, est augue convallis lectus, et aliquet magna arcu nec arcu. Donec at mollis metus. Aenean et mattis velit. Phasellus id enim magna.'
  },
  {
    title: 'Text 2',
    year: 2020,
    body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin rhoncus finibus quam, condimentum tincidunt erat pharetra ac. Nunc ante sapien, congue vitae felis nec, lobortis viverra augue. Integer vitae nibh vel nunc finibus placerat. Aliquam tincidunt magna eros, nec maximus neque accumsan eget. Etiam vitae convallis massa. Donec diam nulla, volutpat a rutrum nec, pulvinar sit amet neque. Donec eleifend ut magna varius condimentum. Morbi eu erat et dolor porta porttitor eget vitae mauris. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Vivamus ornare, risus id ornare sagittis, est augue convallis lectus, et aliquet magna arcu nec arcu. Donec at mollis metus. Aenean et mattis velit. Phasellus id enim magna.'
  },
]

const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear()
const earliestYear = contentList.reduce((prev, curr) => prev.year > curr.year ? curr : prev).year
const timeline = []
for (let year = currentYear; year >= earliestYear; year--) {
  timeline.push({
    year: year,
    contents: contentList.filter(e => e.year === year)
  })
}

const Event = ({ year, title }) => (
  <>
    <div class="col-start-1 ml-auto text-gray-600">
      {year ?? ""}
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-2 m-auto bg-gray-800 shadow-xl w-5 h-1 rounded-full z-10"></div>
    <div class="col-start-3 col-span-3 mr-auto">
      {title &&
      <button class="text-left p-4 rounded-md hover:bg-black hover:text-white">
        <div class="font-medium">{title}</div>
      </button>}
    </div>
  </>
)

const Grid = () => (
  <div class="relative grid grid-cols-5 lg:2/5 xl:w-1/3">
    <div class="col-start-2 mx-auto mb-2 text-gray-600">
      Present
    </div>
    <div class="col-start-2 mx-auto">
      <div class="border-w-1 absolute border-gray-700 h-full border"></div>
    </div>
    {timeline.map(({ year, contents }) => 
      <>
        {contents.map(e => <Event title={e.title} />)}
        <Event year={year} />
      </>
    )}
  </div>
)

const Content = ({ content }) => (
  <div class="ml-8 lg:3/5 xl:w-2/3">
    <h5>{content.title}</h5>
    <p>{content.body}</p>
  </div>
)

export const Parent = () => {  
  return (
    <section class="md:h-screen px-10 pt-10 flex items-center">
      <div class="flex flex-col">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <div class="flex flex-col lg:flex-row items-center">
          <Grid />
          <Content content={contentList[0]} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}
```

The timeline is basically a list of objects having 'year' and 'contents' as properties. The contents list is filled with content from the same year.

I'm dynamically generating the grid cells using the contentList. It works fine on larger screens, with the Grid and Content components appearing side-by-side like so

[image]

On smaller screens, it looks like this currently:

[image]

I would like the Grid to be horizontally aligned on smaller screens, ie, the columns should become rows, with years on top, a line in the middle and the text at the bottom.

Is this possible to do with Tailwind?

Comment: Yes it's possible. Tailwind has viewport dimension keywords available. `sm, md, lg, xl 2xl`. Here are the definitions: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/responsive-design If you need something outside of the pre-defined sets, you'll have to make your own CSS for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So should I write `grid-rows-3 md:grid-cols-3` if I want 3 rows (and as many columns as needed) for small screens and 3 columns (and as many rows as required) for larger screens?

Comment: You need to have each column be a row for whichever viewport size you want them to be on top of each other, as shown in your second picture. My suggestion would be to start with the row format as default, then change them to columns on larger screens (the mobile first approach, which is considered best practice).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to set the grid columns to `1fr`.

example: `grid-template-columns: 1fr`

You'd need to find a tailwindcss equivalent of that.